# Will the solution of the boundary value problem be unique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that we have the following boundary value problem:

$$a^2 u_{xx}=u_t, 0<x<L, t>0 \\ u(x,0)=f(x) , 0 \leq x \leq L\\ u(0,t)=0, u(L,t)=0, t>0$$

By supposing that $u(x,t)=X(x) T(t)$ we find that the solution is of the form $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n e^{-\frac{n^2 \pi^2 a^2 t}{L^2}} \sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}$

where $c_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}$.

But do we know that this solution is unique? Or could there also be an other solution that will not be of the form $X(x) T(t)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the solution of this boundary value problem (heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions) is unique. If we have two solutions $u,v$ then $w = u-v$ satisfy the same PDE and takes the value $0$ on all of the boundaries. Multiply the PDE for $w$ by $w$ and integrate over $[0,L]$ to get

$$\int_0^L ww_t{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^L w^2{\rm d}x = a^2 \int_0^Lw_{xx}w{\rm d}x = -a^2 \int_0^Lw_{x}^2{\rm d}x \leq 0$$

where we integrated by parts in the last equality. This shows that the energy $E(t) = \int_0^L w^2(x,t){\rm d}x$, which by definition is positive, is decreasing. By the boundary conditions we have $E(0) = 0$ so we must have $E(t) \equiv 0$ for all $t>0$ and therefore $w(x,t)\equiv 0$.